# Catch Zend PDO Exception

Tags: zend-framework, exception, pdo, try-catch

I'm wondering if I can put a try catch about `$application->bootstrap()->run();`
that will catch `pdo exceptions`

This works, but it catches every exception, which I do not want.

```
try {
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

I had a nasty incident of pdo exception being throw and displaying the password from application.ini!

Worthy of note, I have tried PDOException, it doesnt get catched.

My DB is set up in bootstrap run() with

```
    try {
        $db = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
        Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $db);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 1;exit;
    }
```

Note that if I put in the wrong password locally and run the app, I do not see 1, I see a blank page even with error reporting on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go where you have the database code and put try catch around that code. If you want only Pdo Exceptions then catch only PdoException. Put something like catch(PdoExcetion_OR_What_Its_Name_Is $e) (And disable the error output to the screen. Write your errors to a log file)

Comment: Updated my post to reflect what Ive tried in relation to this.

Comment: Read more  about PdoException here http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Answer (score 2):

if i understand the question correctly , it mean you are trying to catch you db connection exception

and this would be as easy as these lines below :

```
try {
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $parameters);
    $db->getConnection();
} catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps a failed login credential, or perhaps the RDBMS is not running
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps factory() failed to load the specified Adapter class
}
```

basically `getConnection` function is trying to connect to db with the parameters , if it failed 
it would throw an `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` and if succesfully connected it would return `PDO object`

similarly , you can use this pattern to catch you `Zend_Db` exceptions  or `PDO_Exceptions` in controller classes or models that throw these kind of errors , but not the whole application

Comment: This is more like it, unfortunately in my bootstrap run, I have $db = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter(); I don't have a call to zend db, so I can customize the experience to put a try catch around it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems rather strange to try and catch a whole application. Disabling error reporting (such as [display_errors](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in php.ini) would be a lot better to stop revealing any sensitive information from uncatched exceptions.

But to answer your question:

```
try {
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

This should catch only PDO Exceptions.

Comment: PDOException doesn't return anything for me, even though I thought it should also.

Comment: Have you set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to throw exceptions? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)