# How to log database errors in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, zend-db

I am using zend framework 1.12 for my project. I want to catch all types of fatal errors and send them to an email address for quick fix. I have written the below mentioned code in Bootstrap.php file for this purpose.

```
protected function _initFatalErrorCatcher()
{
    register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'errorlogHandler'));
}

public function errorlogHandler()
{
    $e = error_get_last();

if (!is_null($e)) { //fatal error

    $msg  = 'Fatal error: ' . $e['message'];
    $msg .= ' in' . $e['file'];
    $msg .= ' on line: ' . $e['line'];

    $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($msg);
    $mail->setFrom('zzz@z.com');
    $mail->addTo('yyy@y.com');
    $mail->setSubject('check this error');

    $mail->send();
    }
}
```

Using the above code, i am able to send fatal errors other than database connection related errors and query related errors to email. I followed the instructions from [Catch Zend PDO Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345274/catch-zend-pdo-exception) as well, but i believe i am missing something as its not working.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am also using Zend_Log to write the error logs in a log-file. But, using this i could not find a way to write the fatal errors. Code for this is given below.

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH  . "/../data/log-file.log");
$errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');
$exception = $errors->exception;

$log = new Zend_Log($writer);
$log->debug($exception->getMessage() . "\n" . $exception->getTraceAsString());
```

**Scenario for database connection related issue:**

If there is any error in host name, database name or in user name, it shows a Fatal error in browser like below. But its not detected by register_shutdown_function() or  Zend_Log().

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'AAAA'@'%' to database 'BBBB'' in /var/www/project_name/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144 PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'AAAA'@'%' to database 'BBBB' in /var/www/project_name/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129
```

Comment: I already used that but using Zend_Log i didn't find a way to to list the fatal errors. Please check my edit part in the above post for details.

Comment: Do you have an example of a type of error that this is failing on... really hard errors (like syntax errors) are not going to be resolvable by any means, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: The place you want to put your try catch block is in the index.php, there is a line near the bottom that says $app->bootstrap()->run(); change that to $app->bootstrap(); try {$app->run()} catch(Exception $exception){ /*your exception log code*/ }

Comment: I tried your suggestion but not working. Please check 'Scenario for database connection related issue:' in above post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by writing the below mentioned code in Bootstrap.php file.

```
protected function _initDbConfig()
{
  $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
  $params = $config->database->toArray();
  try {
     $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $params);
     $db->getConnection();

  } catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps the RDBMS is not running
    // code to send email goes here
  } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps factory() failed to load the specified Adapter class
    // code to send email goes here         
  }
}
```

In application.ini, i have the following code.

```
database.host     = "localhost"
database.username = "AAAA"
database.password = "*****"
database.dbname   = "BBBBB"
```

Answer (score 1):

The post [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) shows an example.  Basically use `set_error_handler` to tickle php into throwing exceptions when an error is encountered. This example from link:

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

//$array contains the values for insert

```
try {
    $this->db->insert('Users', $array );
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any other option to check this and database connection using index.php or bootstrap rather than implementing the try catch method in every single query?

Comment: You Could include "/Zend/Db/Exception.php" in your index.php and wrap the whole Boostrapping with an try/catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e)